# Finding a user's manager record in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, adsi

Using Active Directory,  am trying to find the SamAccountName and email of the user’s manager.

I find the logged on user in the AD by search where sAMAccountName = Domain\Account. I then retrieve the manager property, which looks like this, for example:

```
CN=Doe\, Jane E.,OU=Employees,OU=Users,OU=Detroit,OU=United States,DC=na,DC=gmc,DC=gmc,DC=com"
```

How can I use this presumed key to find the user record for this person? What field would I match on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, that is their Distinguished Name, which means you can use it as the direct reference to their profile

```
LDAP://CN=Doe, Jane E.,OU=Employees,OU=Users,OU=Detroit,OU=United States,DC=na,DC=gmc,DC=gmc,DC=com
```

I also think it will return that name if the profile exists. If it has been deleted then I believe it runs a GUID of some sort (based on memory - this might be incorrect)

Comment: From there, how do I directly get the email address using this solution, I am referencing this post in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897812/query-active-directory-to-get-the-email-property-of-a-distinguished-name-directl

Answer (score 1):

The entry for the manager is the manager's Binding String. You can feed it back into a request to active directory by binding it to an object that will return the manager's information.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a post from old time, but I thought might be useful for others in the community)

You can use string stripping and find it like this:

`REPLACE(SUBSTRING(manager, 4, CHARINDEX('OU=', manager)-5), '\', '')`

Full working query (just change DOMAIN to your own):

```
SELECT Top 901 manager, REPLACE(SUBSTRING(manager, 4, CHARINDEX('OU=', 
manager)-5), '\', '')
FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI, 'SELECT manager FROM ''LDAP://DC=DOMAIN,DC=local'' 
     WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' AND objectClass= ''user''
     AND userprincipalname = ''*'' AND mail = ''*'' AND SN = ''*'' ')
```